# how to implement cached video feed like on TikTok

Tags: flutter, listview, video-streaming

I looked everywhere and I could not find a good solution that includes both caching and a smooth video start.

How can I display cached video streams on a listview (or viewpager), preload the next video so that there is no delay when the user goes there.

Essentially, I need a TikTok/Instagram video feed.

Thanks